# How properly work with big data using Swing - performance tips

Tags: java, mysql, swing

There is an application that I'm basically writing with Swing, JDBC and MySQL.

- In DB there are tables like Article, Company, Order, Transaction, Client etc.
- So also there are java classes which describes them.
- User can create,    update, delete information about them.

I give an example of my problem. The article characterizes with id, name, price, company, unit. And when user wants to save new article he chooses the company for this article from the list of all companies. This list in perspective could be really big.

Now I could think of two ways to solve this.

1. When application starts, it connects to the DB and load all the data with which then I will work.

   ```
   public final class AllInformationController {
   public static final Collection<Company> COMPANIES= new HashSet<>(1_000_000);
   public static final Collection<Article> ARTICLES= new HashSet<>(1_000_000);
   public static final Collection<Order> ORDERS= new HashSet<>(1_000_000);
   public static final Collection<Transaction> transactionsHistory= new HashSet<>(10_000_000);
   //etc...
   private AllInformationController() {}
   }
   ```

   Then if user wants for example to change some Company data (like address or telephone etc.), after doing it the program should update the DB info for that company.
2. The second approach is basically to connect to the database every time user queries or changes some information. So then I will mostly work with `ResultSet's`.

I prefer the second way, but just not sure if it's the best one. Think there should be more productive ways to work with data that could be less expensive.

Comment: Sounds like a job for jpa

Comment: @Andreas jpa is the next level :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd approach is better, although there's probably a best case that lies somewhere between them. The 2nd approach here allows multiple applications (or users of the same application) to modify the data at the same time, as the 1st approach may end up using old data if you load all the data at once (especially if a user leaves the application on a while). I would go with the 2nd approach and then figure out what optimizations to make.

Since you think the 1st approach may be usable, I'd assume then you don't have too many users who would use the tool at the same time. If that is the case then, perhaps then you don't need to use any optimizations that the 1st method itself would give you as there's not going to be too much database usage.

When you say you working with ResultSets more often in the 2nd approach than the 1st, well it doesn't need to be that way. You can use the same methods from the 1st approach which translates your data into Java data structures to be used in the 2nd approach.

Answer (score 1):

You already made a very bad decision *here*:

```
And when user wants to save new article he chooses the company for this article
from the _list_ of all companies
```

A *list* works only reasonably if the number of choices is fairly limited; below 10-20 you may get away with a combo box. For thousands of choices a list is very cumbersome, and the further it grows the slower and more unwieldly chosing from a list becomes.

This is typically solved by some kind of *search field* (e.g. user types customer number, presses tab and information is fetched), possibly combined with a search dialog (with more search options and a way to select a result found as "it").

Since you will typically be selecting only a few items with a search request, directly quering the DB is usually practical. For a search dialog you may need to artificially limit the number of results (using specific SQL clauses for paging).

Comment: I typed wrong. The data not in the list, but displays in a table. Anyway it's the same thing. I was thinking about doing search through this table, so maybe it's a good idea. If I do some search dialog, could it possible to do "live search" in the DB through JTextField ? - So for example user types the name of article and some listener will go to DB and then offer list with names to choose  ? I'm asking, because haven't tried to do this and so don't know if this approach will be quick enough.

Comment: @Mark How well live search works depends mainly on your DB, fiddling a bit with when you start searching (e.g. after X characters have been entered) usually is workable. Hooking into a JTextField can be a lot of work, while in principle simple, you need to deal with threading (for the actual SQL query) plus some potentially tricky focus management (for the select results popup). I have done something similar a few years ago (where we hacked JComboBox for this). It was a major hassle to get it work consistently across look and feels (events happening in slightly different order etc.).

Comment: Could you give a sample of perfoming query in another thread and displaying results, because my version of this is really slow and have some bugs. Also i found out that there is two main ways to to autocomplete. 1. using swingx AutoCompletition 2. with Java2AutoComplete. Maybe you suggest which one of them i should use ?